# The difference between if item == "If" and if 'If' in item?

Tags: python, python-3.x

my code is here

```
        for index, item in enumerate(actdiagram, start=1):
          print(item+"&")
          # if item == "If":
          if 'If' in item:
             os.write(fd, ("if").encode('ascii'))
             indexOfIf = index

          elif index == (indexOfIf+1):
            os.write(fd, ("\"" + item + "\" then \n").encode('ascii'))

          else:
            os.write(fd, ("-->" + item + "\n").encode('ascii'))
```

My Question is my code does not go through  `if item == "If"`but it works fine for `if 'If' in item:` 
I wanted to know why it happen like this.

Comment: `if item == "If"` means if `item` is string and has `If` as its content while as `if "If" in item:` means `If` is contained inside an object `item`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`==` checks that both things are the same, where as `in` checks that the second thing *contains* the first.

```
>>> "foo" in "blah blah foo blah blah"
True
>>> "foo" == "blah blah foo blah blah"
False
```

Here, `foo` is in the second string, but it also contains other things.

In your case, it would appear that `item` is not the string `"If"`, but it does contain it.

Comment: i figured out it..in my code before this i append a space foe each item. that is the case it does not work for == . thank you sir.